# Generating and Referring to Reduced Latin Squares

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

I've been looking online for information about latin squares and I came across this overview: http://ccom.uprrp.edu/~labemmy/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/4_Presentation_Some-Properties-of-Latin-Squares_March2009.pdf

The content at the link above indicates that the number (and presumably specific configurations) of reduced latin squares of order 11 or less are known. What methods have been used to identify those reduced latin squares? (I am less interested in the non-reduced variety at this time.) Is there associated nomenclature or indexing to be able to refer to a specific reduced latin square of a given order?